# Push to TestFlight without Admin Account?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

If possible, is there a way to push to TestFlight without access to the Admin or Account Holder accounts?

I keep getting shut down at the Signing Certificate stage in XCode.

Ideally, I'm trying to figure out a way to continue development (+ test and bug fixes), push to TestFlight, and repeat.  However, I was only granted developer level access.

We do have contact with the account holder/admins -- is there a way they can create a cert in a way that will let development continue + pushed to TestFlight on a regular basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a distribution certificate to push the app into TestFlight.
Get that from your admin in .p12 format, install it in the keychain.
Use that certificate while signing and upload it into the test flight

Comment: So, I finally got the distribution certificate p12 from the admin -- however, when I archive -> iOS App Store -> Upload... When I try automatically manage signing, I'm punted to the "need an admin account" error screen. When I try to manually manage the signing, XCode doesn't see the dist cert.  What am I doing wrong? or is there a good resource on how to properly use (and validate maybe) the dist cert?

Comment: can you check if you are logged in with your id in xcodepreferences->account?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not 100% on what happened. A horrid spree of button smashing and the app made it to test flight! (Gonna replicate on a coworkers machine to see what turns were taken). Had a small trip with provisioning profiles. But looks like we're good to go. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You must have a development account as an administrator if you are with the person role, if you are a company account, you must have an account that has permission to test, without the account you must generate a .p12 from https://developer.apple. com and with that you can sign the app and upload it to the store, otherwise without a development membership you can not do it.

Answer (score 1):

Developer role is enough for uploading builds. The issue you have is not with uploading but with signing. Apparently, you don't have a distribution certificate to sign your build. So, you should receive a distribution certificate with the private key from account holder/admin. Or, they could lift your role to App Manager and then you'll be able to create distribution certificate on your own (a not ideal solution in some cases like many separate teams/devs on one developer account).